# yocto build for iMX6 TinyRex Module not booting

Tags: yocto, imx6

I am trying to build an image for the iMX6 TinyRex module using yocto. I don't encounter any issues during the build process, everything seems to be working. However when I copy the finished image to an sd card and plug it in, it doesn't boot up. I just get a blank screen.

I'm following this tutorial:

http://www.imx6rex.com/imx6-tiny-rex/software/how-to-start-with-yocto-and-compile-source-codes/

I tried several different images, but none seem to work.
I took over this project from someone else and am pretty new to yocto.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try this: http://wiki.voipac.com/xwiki/bin/view/imx6+tinyrex/yocto#HBuildingimages I got it working without problems.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately I"d already tried this tutorial, but made no difference. Still couldn't get it to boot. I managed to get a hold of an older build of an image and used that images uboot and kernel. I got that to work with the filesystem I built.